# UIImageView web image caching issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a class in my app called `RemoteImageView` that takes in an image URL and retrieves that image from the web, and caches it for faster future retrieval.

I am having issues with duplicate images displaying for my `UIImageView` is inside a `UICollectionView`.

It seems that the return from `downloadImageWithURL` is calling back to the wrong instance on `RemoteImageView` and as you can see I have tried to test for it by having a reference to `currentRequest` that I check upon the callback to `showLoadedImage` before I set the image.

Is it obvious to anyone what I am doing wrong here? The "WRONG IMAGE REQUEST!" logging prints out quite a bit, but sometimes it doesn't print out and the wrong (duplicate) images are set.

---

```
- (void) loadImage
{
    // Create response with url and check if the image is already in the cache
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:request];

    // Save a reference to the image request to make sure we return the correct request
    currentRequest = request;

    if (!image) {
        [SDWebImageDownloader.sharedDownloader downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                            options:0
                                                           progress:NULL
                                                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished)
         {
             if (image && finished) {
                 // Save the image into cached memory
                 [[UIImageView sharedImageCache] cacheImage:image forRequest:request];

                 [self showLoadedImage:image forRequest:request];
             }
         }];

    } else {
        [self showLoadedImage:image forRequest:request];
    }
}

- (void) showLoadedImage:(UIImage *) image forRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    // Check the request is the one we requested (bug with wrong images displaying)
    if ([currentRequest isEqual:request]) {

        [self setImage:image];

    } else {
        MWLogDebug(@"WRONG IMAGE REQUEST!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Re: this line: `if (image && finished)`, what does your code for declaring `finished` look like?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you declare NSURLRequest and after that you run async operation in the background. Before the completed handler will launch (it can take few sec), you can create another (or even more) NSURLRequest which will override currentRequest. So the currentRequest in showLoadedImage: could be not what you hoping.

Comment: @AdrianB this is just the default SDWebImage (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) finished parameter

Comment: Thanks @Greg, so what should I do to fix this in your opinion? I still need to reference the request in the completion block..

Comment: If you decided to use `SDWebImage` why are you trying to maintain cache by yourself as well as getting your own `NSURLRequest`, it should do it automatically. All you need is just provide `imageURL` which is used as `id` for checking if image is in cache. You can also use their method for async updating `UIImageView.imageView`.